# In angular, how to call a function defined inside a controller of directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Here is code:**

**Directive code:**

```js
angular.module('app', ['localytics.directives', 'ngLoadScript'])
.directive("home", function() {
 return {
  restrict: "A",
  replace: true,
  template: "<div ng-include='var'>{{var}}</div>",
  controller: function($scope) {
   //loading home page - as default
   $scope.var = "/tfm/home.html"
   //on change the page changed dynamically!
   $scope.change = function(where) {
    $scope.var = where;
   }
  }
 }
})
```

I WANT TO CALL chanage(where) FUNCTION OF DIRECTIVE - DEFINED IN CONTROLLER OF DIRECTIVE.

**Controller Code:**

```js
.controller('wToEatController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.submitInfoAboutTable = function() {
  //validation for time selection
  if($scope.idealTableTime == undefined || $scope.rightTableTime == undefined) {
   return;
  }
  
  //Booking details to be updated - here users preference is updating!
  var bookingDetails = {
   idealTableWaitTime: $scope.idealTableTime,
   rightTableWaitTime: $scope.rightTableTime
  }
  
  //Let's update booking information - the booking key will be same used while login, public/tfm.html
  FirebaseDbService.updateBooking(function(isUpdated) {
   console.log(isUpdated);
   //I WANT TO CALL chanage(where) function of DIRECTIVE
   $scope.change = "change('/tfm/home.html')";
  }, bookingDetails, bookingKey);
 } 
}]);
```

**Is it possible?**

Comment: make a service not directive

Comment: service is not working, that will not set template: 
template: "<div ng-include='var'>{{var}}</div>"

Comment: inject that service to both directive and controller

Comment: Could you please add an example? Will help me!

Comment: may be something like http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/geaab/, but you don't need to use $broadcast to call a function from service.

Comment: I am confused, so perhaps I am not helping, but isolated scope should do this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an attribute with which the link will be done (in this example `customAttr`):

```
<span yourDirectiveName  customAttr="myFunctionLink(funcInDirective)"></span>
```

And into your directive controller just set the new attribute like in the following snippet( `'&'` two way data binding ) , and create a connection with your directive method :

```
scope : {customAttr : '&'},
link : function(scope,element,attrs){

        scope.myDirectiveFunc = function(){
             console.log("my directive function was called");}
        }
        scope.customAttr({funcInDirective : scope.myDirectiveFunc});
}
```

And in your controller :

```
$scope.myFunctionLink = function(funcInDirective){
$scope.callableDirectiveFunc = funcInDirective;}
```

Now you can call your directive function with `$scope.callableDirectiveFunc();`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me Stefan!

Comment: Glad I could help :)